# Difference between group homomorphism and homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the difference between a group homomorphism and a homomorphism?

Comment: It's the same as the difference between an element and a group element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A homomorphism is a mapping between two algebraic objects which preserves operation in those objects. The object may be a group, ring, field or some spaces or algebras. A group homomorphism is a homomorphism where the objects are groups.

Answer (score 3):

As Samprity describes, a [homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) is the more general term: it is a function between two algebraic structures preserving the operation(s) defining those structures, and, in general, is structure-preserving. A homomorphism might be a function between [groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism), between [rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism), between fields (abstract algebra), between vector spaces, or between two more general structures ([algebra homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_homomorphism)), which preserves the structures in question. We can also have *[graph homomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism)* - mapping from one graph to another that preserves the structure of the graphs.

A *[group homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism)* **is** a homomorphism, but is specifically describing a structure-preserving function between two algebraic **groups**.

Given two groups $(G, ∗)$ and $(H, ·)$, a *group homomorphism* from $(G, ∗)$ to $(H, ·)$ is a function $h : G → H$ such that for all $x, y \in G$, it holds that
$$h(x*y) = h(x) \cdot h(y) $$